# Python Libraries are not importing into Pycharm

Tags: python, import, pip, pycharm, shared-libraries

I am using Pycharm and I have the latest versions, I reinstalled everything today.

I want to install `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` and I do it with Pycharm settings and Python Interpreter. I add them there and click OK. I handle the path and all, but it keeps showing my import is unused or does not exist.

When I type: `import requests`, it is ok for 1 second, then it goes grey and gives me an error. Does anyone have any tips on this?

[image]

I have changed the path, done the environment thing and reinstalled twice.

Comment: The fact that `requests` is grey means you’re not using it in that file. If you use it, it should be marked as used.

Comment: it's just a warning and not an error. if you run it it will pass

Comment: it means that you haven't used the import (ie. called `requests.get()`), not that it's necessarily unavailable

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, it's only a warning. Pycharm is telling you that you have imported a library but you're not using this library (request). If you use the library the warning disappears